# problem with php function implode newline

Tags: php, newline, implode

Hello so I'm writing a php code that allows me to stock the result of  sql query in a php array and then Iam conerting the array into a string using the function implode and I am trying to put each row of the table in a new line but when i echo the string I keep having all my results in the same line.

```
$data=array();
$req=$bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableciqual WHERE (CONVERT(`alim_nom` USING utf8)) LIKE  ?");
$req->execute(array("%$nom%"));
while($resultat=$req->fetch()){
    $data[] =$resultat['alim_nom'];
}
$d=implode("\r\n",$data);
echo $d;
```

Comment: Have you surrounded the output with `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags, or put the output somewhere where the browser will respect the newline?

Comment: `implode("<br>",$data);` ?

Comment: the solution with <br> works when I echo my result on a web page but I am trying to echo the result on dialogflow and the response contains the <br> instead of putting each result in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<br/>` tag inside the `implode` function, instead of line-terminators in case of a web-browser. Markup languages like HTML/XML do not process line-terminators by default. For example,

- A newline `'\n'`
- A carriage-return `'\r'`
- A next-line `'\u0085'`
- A line-separator `'\u2028'`
- A paragraph-separator `'\u2029`

are not processed as they should be **(by default in a web browser)**. Instead the browser treats them as **"whitespaces"**.

If you want to use them, then you can either

- Wrap the variable/output with a `<pre>` tag, which will explicitly tell the browser to also do non-HTML formatting (like in this case for line-terminators).
- Use the `nl2br()` function, which will convert line-terminators to `<br/>`

Ideally you would want to replace line-terminators with the line-break `<br/>` tag.